# HTML file not displaying everything from server location in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Good day,

I have an HTML document which I have developed. The HTML document works perfectly fine (even with IE) when i run it from a local destination.

When I put the HTML document on the server and run it from the server's location with IE some of my text disappears. This only happens when I open it with IE from the server, if I open the HTML document with Chrome or Mozilla from the server it works fine. I've made sure that all my text and pictures is on the server with the rest of the documents.

Please advise on this issue. I have done a lot of research but can not understand or find out why exactly this is happening.

HTML code below for the section that does not appear:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body style=background-image:url('Images/blue.jpg')>

        <section id="body" class="width" >


            <aside id="sidebar" class="column-left">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="Images/VsoftLogo.jpg" alt="thumbnail" />
            <h2 class ="sidebar-heading">LOGINS</h2>
            <nav id="mainnav">
                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <hr>
                            </ul>
            </nav>

            <h2 class ="sidebar-heading">LOGINS2</h2>
            <nav id="mainnav">
                <ul>
                                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <hr>
                            </ul>
            </nav>


            </aside>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without looking at your code it's really hard to help, however note that `/` is not the same as `\` (when referring to folder structure).

Comment: Please post your code so we have a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Maybe encoding?

Comment: Please see updated post.

I tried to change the encoding in IE but did not solve the problem.

Comment: I really do not understand why it works perfectly fine with any browser when i open it locally but as soon as I open it from the server's location with IE my side-bar text is gone.

Comment: Also note that in linux servers files/folders are case sensitive, so if in your local machine you have the folder `Css` but inside your server the folder's name is `css` - this will not work.

Comment: F12 to display the IE Dev tool, on the Emulation tab, you will find which IE Emulation Mode the site is using and how it was established eg. IE7 users compatibility view list, meta x-ua, display intranet sites in compatibility view. Use the File>Properties menu in IE to determine which IE security zone it maps to.... you may have Tools>Compatibility view settings , "Display intranet sites in compatibility view" selected.

Comment: One concept that's not yet been raised is the fact that IE implements [security zones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537183(v=vs.85).aspx); that is, files opened from the Internet are loaded in a different zone than those loaded from the local machine or the Intranet.  The differences you're seeing may be due to different security settings between the Internet, Intranet, and Local Machine Zone, etc.